# Selenium located the element but it fails to click on it

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

So I was trying to get the mp4 url from the video [url](https://fembed-hd.com/v/l364xun6eeqrx67). I tried to locate the div and click on it but it failed to even locate it. So I tried locating the svg inside it and located it successfully but whenever I try to click on it try to get the requests made by the website I don't get the requests made and the element does not get clicked. Whenever I try not to click it I get the requests made but when I try to click I only get errors and stack trace-

The Code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from seleniumwire import webdriver  # Import from
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#Chrome Stuff
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')

#All the driver Stuff
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
# driver.get("https://youtube.com")
url = 'https://fembed-hd.com/v/l364xun6eeqrx67'
driver.get(url)
# driver.implicitly_wait(0.5)

# Clicking...
body = driver.find_element(by=By.TAG_NAME, value='body')
body.click()
parent = driver.window_handles[0]
driver.switch_to.window(parent)

body.click()
parent = driver.window_handles[0]
driver.switch_to.window(parent)

# BTN Stuff
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
btnplay = driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "svg")
print(btnplay)
btnplay.click()

driver.implicitly_wait(2)
# Access requests via the `requests` attribute
for request in driver.requests:
    if request.response:
        print(request.url)
driver.quit()
driver.close()
```

The console with click method -

```
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="fb0fadcbd64dc589211b0f3ef7052618", element="0f996a92-3f40-497e-a7f1-ff7dedb5e945")>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 38, in <module>
    btnplay.click()
  File "/home/runner/justforfun/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 81, in click
    self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
  File "/home/runner/justforfun/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 710, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "/home/runner/justforfun/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 425, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/home/runner/justforfun/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 247, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
  (Session info: headless chrome=97.0.4692.71)
Stacktrace:
#0 0x55691c752f23 <unknown>
#1 0x55691c21d6cf <unknown>
#2 0x55691c254a27 <unknown>
#3 0x55691c248899 <unknown>
#4 0x55691c271182 <unknown>
#5 0x55691c248163 <unknown>
#6 0x55691c27128e <unknown>
#7 0x55691c2843db <unknown>
#8 0x55691c271073 <unknown>
#9 0x55691c246bca <unknown>
#10 0x55691c247c95 <unknown>
#11 0x55691c78273d <unknown>
#12 0x55691c798a40 <unknown>
#13 0x55691c784435 <unknown>
#14 0x55691c799465 <unknown>
#15 0x55691c777e6f <unknown>
#16 0x55691c7b42d8 <unknown>
#17 0x55691c7b4458 <unknown>
#18 0x55691c7cf1fd <unknown>
#19 0x7f779ae0cd40 <unknown>
```

As you can see I don't even get the requests made. I need the requests made after clicking the svg play button. Please help Me. I will be grateful and glad for hearing the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, after clicking on some element there and getting back to the original page I could click on `svg` element to start play the video.
The issues here are: To click on correct element and to locate elements with special tag names like `svg`.
Once the ad is opened we can play the video. It can be done not by clicking the `svg` (picture) element only.
So, my code is:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
url = 'https://fembed-hd.com/v/l364xun6eeqrx67'
driver.get(url)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@style,'fixed')]"))).click()

parent = driver.window_handles[0]
driver.switch_to.window(parent)

driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[name()='svg']").click()
```

Comment: How can I wait to print the .mp4 request? Because after the click I want to get the mp4 request??

Comment: And I have one more doubt that selenium is not waiting for the video to be played. That's why I don't get the mp4 request. How can I fix that? Any help would be apreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure I know how to do that. Selenium deals with GUI elements, not with requests. At least this is the main Selenium feature. I can give a solution based on GUI elements to see the video started playing. Please open a new question for that and I will try to answer there

Comment: So as you know I still have problem. I have posted the question please check me out there.

Comment: The question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71634956/not-able-to-scrape-a-valid-mp4-url

Comment: I'm not really familiar with dealing with requests with selenium but I'll try to see how can I help there

Comment: Hey prophet I have a favor to ask you. Can  you answer this selenium question too plz plz. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71703354/the-element-doesnt-load-and-selenium-is-not-able-to-click/71704770?noredirect=1#comment126741514_71704770