# Not able to scrape a valid mp4 url

Tags: python, selenium, python-requests, seleniumwire

I am working on a scraper; more particularly fembed scraper using this [url](https://fembed-hd.com/v/l364xun6eeqrx67). I began with clicking on the play button then capturing the request made. But how am I going to store that request and when I click on the mp4 url captured in the console it says 403 forbidden but when I manually open the network tab after clicking on the play button I get an mp4 url which works.

The code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from seleniumwire import webdriver  # Import from

#Chrome Stuff
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
driver.maximize_window()
url = 'https://fembed-hd.com/v/l364xun6eeqrx67'
driver.get(url)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@style,'fixed')]"))).click()

parent = driver.window_handles[0]
driver.switch_to.window(parent)

driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[name()='svg']").click()
driver.switch_to.window(parent)

driver.wait_for_request('https://fvs.io/redirector?')
# driver.wait_for_request('https://www2252.ff-05.com/', 20)
# Access requests via the `requests` attribute
for request in driver.requests:
    if request.response:
        print(request.url)
        print(request.response.headers)
driver.quit()
driver.close()
```

The console -

```
https://fembed-hd.com/v/l364xun6eeqrx67
date: Sun, 27 Mar 2022 08:50:35 GMT
content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
vary: Accept-Encoding
last-modified: Sat, 26 Mar 2022 19:06:11 GMT
cache-control: max-age=1800
cf-cache-status: HIT
age: 1602
expect-ct: max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"
report-to: {"endpoints":[{"url":"https:\/\/a.nel.cloudflare.com\/report\/v3?s=4PC21M6XGpbIiQy1y%2Bxx%2BNEbh5uc3Xn0UY6%2FHEZdwDhodfTEmqAfjgmSgJd6iZRzTC65XhH2WFJ1KvhMzPewMiZMR8YEz4SZXjJo0raJCTJKZjI8sdX0%2FoV91ECNc2cY"}],"group":"cf-nel","max_age":604800}
nel: {"success_fraction":0,"report_to":"cf-nel","max_age":604800}
server: cloudflare
cf-ray: 6f26e11b6d74681d-SEA
content-encoding: br
alt-svc: h3=":443"; ma=86400, h3-29=":443"; ma=86400


https://fembed-hd.com/asset/default/player/base.js?v=1595607720
date: Sun, 27 Mar 2022 08:50:35 GMT
content-type: application/javascript; charset=UTF-8
vary: Accept-Encoding
vary: Accept-Encoding
last-modified: Fri, 24 Jul 2020 16:22:00 GMT
etag: W/"5f1b0aa8-30eae"
access-control-allow-credentials: true
cache-control: max-age=31536000
cf-cache-status: HIT
age: 2348110
expect-ct: max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"
report-to: {"endpoints":[{"url":"https:\/\/a.nel.cloudflare.com\/report\/v3?s=61mDkDwvsacu8THISiB2QGaeX1b%2B8KMCyjTGQi8Zfj1%2BnugawtbUpLoSo0ayKXVDq4i6YsZjY7Zm%2FinXk4DK4AAGjU6%2FE8Rfj0McVdJIcc4XtFhvhjyNoXWg77xHBD%2FQ"}],"group":"cf-nel","max_age":604800}
nel: {"success_fraction":0,"report_to":"cf-nel","max_age":604800}
server: cloudflare
cf-ray: 6f26e11cff9b681d-SEA
content-encoding: br
alt-svc: h3=":443"; ma=86400, h3-29=":443"; ma=86400


https://fembed-hd.com/api/source/l364xun6eeqrx67
date: Sun, 27 Mar 2022 08:50:36 GMT
content-type: application/json
vary: Accept-Encoding
cf-cache-status: DYNAMIC
expect-ct: max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"
report-to: {"endpoints":[{"url":"https:\/\/a.nel.cloudflare.com\/report\/v3?s=BQG7OPNcul4qpUCWYsn5szJsyFBdFKTHkjw0ybVQdb6X30DjqBF1XBPIyYfdBAUxv7ECgVak0zhurx2N9y5obTpBXWPxnKRBm7TH%2BF5sUrpIgKKCeJ%2FKCoQrMOUGwqRP"}],"group":"cf-nel","max_age":604800}
nel: {"success_fraction":0,"report_to":"cf-nel","max_age":604800}
server: cloudflare
cf-ray: 6f26e11e491f681d-SEA
content-encoding: br
alt-svc: h3=":443"; ma=86400, h3-29=":443"; ma=86400


https://mc.yandex.ru/metrika/tag.js
content-length: 69940
date: Sun, 27 Mar 2022 08:50:36 GMT
access-control-allow-origin: *
etag: "623af423-11134"
expires: Sun, 27 Mar 2022 09:50:36 GMT
last-modified: Wed, 23 Mar 2022 13:19:15 GMT
cache-control: max-age=3600
content-encoding: br
content-type: application/javascript
strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000


https://fembed-hd.com/asset/jquery/slim-3.2.min.js?c=US&t=471
date: Sun, 27 Mar 2022 08:50:36 GMT
content-type: application/javascript; charset="utf-8"
vary: Accept-Encoding
cache-control: max-age=31536000, must-revalidate
cf-cache-status: HIT
age: 270575
last-modified: Thu, 24 Mar 2022 05:41:01 GMT
expect-ct: max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"
report-to: {"endpoints":[{"url":"https:\/\/a.nel.cloudflare.com\/report\/v3?s=5EfH%2BKMe%2BkO9hl1Oj%2B3VpnWJbT4soEtA56Q1%2BbHCYwAsaOgtJzWXhsRt%2BBMT2EWVJplbe0REZbZ1Rpbd5UuEI0JfiFtatPoRtm6%2BuTO6NqB8ADe4N54iLsel%2FoO7KBVs"}],"group":"cf-nel","max_age":604800}
nel: {"success_fraction":0,"report_to":"cf-nel","max_age":604800}
server: cloudflare
cf-ray: 6f26e122ae6d681d-SEA
content-encoding: br
alt-svc: h3=":443"; ma=86400, h3-29=":443"; ma=86400


https://fembed-hd.com/asset/userdata/376887/poster/l/36/l364xun6eeqrx67.png?v=1645401494
date: Sun, 27 Mar 2022 08:50:36 GMT
content-type: text/html
content-length: 145
location: https://thumb.fvs.io/asset/userdata/376887/poster/l/36/l364xun6eeqrx67.png?v=1645401494
cf-cache-status: BYPASS
expect-ct: max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"
report-to: {"endpoints":[{"url":"https:\/\/a.nel.cloudflare.com\/report\/v3?s=lo0DL2VLrQRy1BVMYxwLJIHi3Y9L4FH3N6oSKrMI2VjkSidcoVOavbJ%2FqCqNtjs87ocoliBGFGgLfUr%2BLAPpVjLqc5xbt9xZJDxDc6i82lcg%2BoHZthBMS8LNSYPEyVjh"}],"group":"cf-nel","max_age":604800}
nel: {"success_fraction":0,"report_to":"cf-nel","max_age":604800}
vary: Accept-Encoding
server: cloudflare
cf-ray: 6f26e122be7c681d-SEA
alt-svc: h3=":443"; ma=86400, h3-29=":443"; ma=86400


https://mc.yandex.ru/watch/56313682
location: /watch/56313682/1
date: Sun, 27 Mar 2022 08:50:36 GMT
set-cookie: yandexuid=5961363261648371036; Expires=Mon, 27-Mar-2023 08:50:36 GMT; Domain=.yandex.ru; Path=/; SameSite=None; Secure
set-cookie: yuidss=5961363261648371036; Expires=Mon, 27-Mar-2023 08:50:36 GMT; Domain=.yandex.ru; Path=/; SameSite=None; Secure
set-cookie: yabs-sid=878267101648371036; Path=/; SameSite=None; Secure
set-cookie: i=Zm51thCA+wGizigUlxSaiVDK9TwTw6EXEPQ7gfWp4g6az3spy16KvPFudUDfA0FzW4wyoXkDTfmgWSeLDe5o0yoSfq4=; Expires=Wed, 24-Mar-2032 08:50:35 GMT; Domain=.yandex.ru; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=None
set-cookie: ymex=1679907036.yrts.1648371036#1679907036.yrtsi.1648371036; Expires=Mon, 27-Mar-2023 08:50:36 GMT; Domain=.yandex.ru; Path=/; SameSite=None; Secure
pragma: no-cache
x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
expires: Sun, 27-Mar-2022 08:50:36 GMT
last-modified: Sun, 27-Mar-2022 08:50:36 GMT
cache-control: private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, max-age=0
strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000


https://mc.yandex.ru/watch/56313682/1
content-length: 43
date: Sun, 27 Mar 2022 08:50:37 GMT
pragma: no-cache
expires: Sun, 27-Mar-2022 08:50:37 GMT
x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
last-modified: Sun, 27-Mar-2022 08:50:37 GMT
cache-control: private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, max-age=0
content-type: image/gif
strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000


https://thumb.fvs.io/asset/userdata/376887/poster/l/36/l364xun6eeqrx67.png?v=1645401494
date: Sun, 27 Mar 2022 08:50:37 GMT
content-type: image/png
content-length: 276428
last-modified: Sun, 20 Feb 2022 23:58:14 GMT
etag: "6212d596-437cc"
access-control-allow-origin: *
cache-control: max-age=14400
cf-cache-status: HIT
age: 1601
accept-ranges: bytes
expect-ct: max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"
vary: Accept-Encoding
server: cloudflare
cf-ray: 6f26e127afd8147a-SEA


https://mc.yandex.com/sync_cookie_image_check
date: Sun, 27 Mar 2022 08:50:38 GMT
location: https://mc.yandex.ru/sync_cookie_image_start?redirect_domain=mc.yandex.com&token=9590.brzcvz7T-X1vvoQ7cfwQIDiog90YVuDdUmdP86keMYkNjteYAFQlBYUSd-OjqADh.U-FEYgRAlePeVp5YbcARaTY1y0Y%2C
strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000
x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
set-cookie: sync_cookie_csrf=1055933505fake; Expires=Sun, 27-Mar-2022 09:00:38 GMT; Domain=.mc.yandex.com; Path=/; SameSite=None; Secure


https://mc.yandex.com/metrika/advert.gif
content-length: 43
date: Sun, 27 Mar 2022 08:50:38 GMT
access-control-allow-origin: *
etag: "623af423-2b"
expires: Sun, 27 Mar 2022 09:50:38 GMT
accept-ranges: bytes
last-modified: Wed, 23 Mar 2022 13:19:15 GMT
cache-control: max-age=3600
content-type: image/gif
strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000


https://mc.yandex.ru/sync_cookie_image_start?redirect_domain=mc.yandex.com&token=9590.brzcvz7T-X1vvoQ7cfwQIDiog90YVuDdUmdP86keMYkNjteYAFQlBYUSd-OjqADh.U-FEYgRAlePeVp5YbcARaTY1y0Y%2C
date: Sun, 27 Mar 2022 08:50:38 GMT
location: https://mc.yandex.com/sync_cookie_image_decide?token=9590.cd7vJF_R9isKrdo6gshF0pcMmqc-mzv3lE3hPmbHafCieWkdnblEc8Jhelx7DE32e_2CZppywp0yskp9s3A6aioUuk8oAkT77VqRPAc9ZmI%2C.bIKv-YsysCAUEnZgzfDQdpJjhAo%2C
strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000
x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
set-cookie: sync_cookie_csrf=351619929fake; Expires=Sun, 27-Mar-2022 09:00:38 GMT; Domain=.mc.yandex.ru; Path=/; SameSite=None; Secure


https://mc.yandex.com/sync_cookie_image_decide?token=9590.cd7vJF_R9isKrdo6gshF0pcMmqc-mzv3lE3hPmbHafCieWkdnblEc8Jhelx7DE32e_2CZppywp0yskp9s3A6aioUuk8oAkT77VqRPAc9ZmI%2C.bIKv-YsysCAUEnZgzfDQdpJjhAo%2C
content-length: 43
content-type: image/gif
date: Sun, 27 Mar 2022 08:50:38 GMT
strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000
x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
set-cookie: yandexuid=5961363261648371036; Expires=Sat, 22-Mar-2042 08:50:38 GMT; Domain=.yandex.com; Path=/; SameSite=None; Secure
set-cookie: yuidss=5961363261648371036; Expires=Sat, 22-Mar-2042 08:50:38 GMT; Domain=.yandex.com; Path=/; SameSite=None; Secure
set-cookie: sync_cookie_ok=synced; Expires=Mon, 28-Mar-2022 08:50:38 GMT; Domain=.mc.yandex.com; Path=/; SameSite=None; Secure


https://mc.yandex.com/watch/49788082?wmode=7&page-url=https%3A%2F%2Ffembed-hd.com%2Fv%2Fl364xun6eeqrx67&charset=utf-8&site-info=%7B%22owner%22%3A%22376887%22%7D&browser-info=pv%3A1%3Agdpr%3A14%3Avf%3Auq3ipefhyn5rb8pyhvi%3Afp%3A1384%3Afu%3A0%3Aen%3Autf-8%3Ala%3Aen-US%3Av%3A771%3Acn%3A1%3Adp%3A0%3Als%3A858857036685%3Ahid%3A848694538%3Az%3A0%3Ai%3A20220327085037%3Aet%3A1648371037%3Ac%3A1%3Arn%3A197290416%3Arqn%3A1%3Au%3A1648371037727356580%3Aw%3A800x600%3As%3A800x600x24%3Ask%3A1%3Ahdl%3A1%3Antf%3A1%3Ans%3A1648371035103%3Ads%3A0%2C190%2C150%2C43%2C0%2C0%2C%2C299%2C0%2C%2C%2C%2C696%3Awv%3A2%3Aco%3A0%3Aadb%3A2%3Arqnl%3A1%3Ast%3A1648371039%3At%3AVideo%20shingeki-no-kyojin-the-final-season-part-2-episode-71645401122.0.mp4&t=gdpr(14)aw(1)ti(2)
location: /watch/49788082/1?wmode=7&page-url=https%3A%2F%2Ffembed-hd.com%2Fv%2Fl364xun6eeqrx67&charset=utf-8&site-info=%7B%22owner%22%3A%22376887%22%7D&browser-info=pv%3A1%3Agdpr%3A14%3Avf%3Auq3ipefhyn5rb8pyhvi%3Afp%3A1384%3Afu%3A0%3Aen%3Autf-8%3Ala%3Aen-US%3Av%3A771%3Acn%3A1%3Adp%3A0%3Als%3A858857036685%3Ahid%3A848694538%3Az%3A0%3Ai%3A20220327085037%3Aet%3A1648371037%3Ac%3A1%3Arn%3A197290416%3Arqn%3A1%3Au%3A1648371037727356580%3Aw%3A800x600%3As%3A800x600x24%3Ask%3A1%3Ahdl%3A1%3Antf%3A1%3Ans%3A1648371035103%3Ads%3A0%2C190%2C150%2C43%2C0%2C0%2C%2C299%2C0%2C%2C%2C%2C696%3Awv%3A2%3Aco%3A0%3Aadb%3A2%3Arqnl%3A1%3Ast%3A1648371039%3At%3AVideo%20shingeki-no-kyojin-the-final-season-part-2-episode-71645401122.0.mp4&t=gdpr%2814%29aw%281%29ti%282%29
date: Sun, 27 Mar 2022 08:50:38 GMT
access-control-allow-origin: https://fembed-hd.com
set-cookie: yabs-sid=480277731648371038; Path=/; SameSite=None; Secure
set-cookie: i=toqhJwcXLHPLZR5T2xfEnsedYzVr8+xWHGWO0bnMTLz5zftAW//fj8bUtBwahOGPmX4oyBPZms3qpUAqvEaLPxSSV78=; Expires=Wed, 24-Mar-2032 08:50:32 GMT; Domain=.yandex.com; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=None
set-cookie: ymex=1679907038.yrtsi.1648371038; Expires=Mon, 27-Mar-2023 08:50:38 GMT; Domain=.yandex.com; Path=/; SameSite=None; Secure
access-control-allow-credentials: true
pragma: no-cache
x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
expires: Sun, 27-Mar-2022 08:50:38 GMT
last-modified: Sun, 27-Mar-2022 08:50:38 GMT
cache-control: private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, max-age=0
strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000


https://mc.yandex.com/watch/49788082/1?wmode=7&page-url=https%3A%2F%2Ffembed-hd.com%2Fv%2Fl364xun6eeqrx67&charset=utf-8&site-info=%7B%22owner%22%3A%22376887%22%7D&browser-info=pv%3A1%3Agdpr%3A14%3Avf%3Auq3ipefhyn5rb8pyhvi%3Afp%3A1384%3Afu%3A0%3Aen%3Autf-8%3Ala%3Aen-US%3Av%3A771%3Acn%3A1%3Adp%3A0%3Als%3A858857036685%3Ahid%3A848694538%3Az%3A0%3Ai%3A20220327085037%3Aet%3A1648371037%3Ac%3A1%3Arn%3A197290416%3Arqn%3A1%3Au%3A1648371037727356580%3Aw%3A800x600%3As%3A800x600x24%3Ask%3A1%3Ahdl%3A1%3Antf%3A1%3Ans%3A1648371035103%3Ads%3A0%2C190%2C150%2C43%2C0%2C0%2C%2C299%2C0%2C%2C%2C%2C696%3Awv%3A2%3Aco%3A0%3Aadb%3A2%3Arqnl%3A1%3Ast%3A1648371039%3At%3AVideo%20shingeki-no-kyojin-the-final-season-part-2-episode-71645401122.0.mp4&t=gdpr%2814%29aw%281%29ti%282%29
content-length: 357
date: Sun, 27 Mar 2022 08:50:39 GMT
x-content-type-options: nosniff
access-control-allow-origin: https://fembed-hd.com
set-cookie: yandexuid=5961363261648371036; Expires=Mon, 27-Mar-2023 08:50:39 GMT; Domain=.yandex.com; Path=/; SameSite=None; Secure
set-cookie: yuidss=5961363261648371036; Expires=Mon, 27-Mar-2023 08:50:39 GMT; Domain=.yandex.com; Path=/; SameSite=None; Secure
set-cookie: ymex=1679907039.yrts.1648371039#1679907038.yrtsi.1648371038; Expires=Mon, 27-Mar-2023 08:50:39 GMT; Domain=.yandex.com; Path=/; SameSite=None; Secure
access-control-allow-credentials: true
pragma: no-cache
x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
expires: Sun, 27-Mar-2022 08:50:39 GMT
last-modified: Sun, 27-Mar-2022 08:50:39 GMT
cache-control: private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, max-age=0
content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000


https://fembed-hd.com/asset/default/player/related.js
date: Sun, 27 Mar 2022 08:50:39 GMT
content-type: application/javascript; charset=UTF-8
vary: Accept-Encoding
vary: Accept-Encoding
last-modified: Sat, 30 Mar 2019 16:13:45 GMT
etag: W/"5c9f95b9-182da"
access-control-allow-credentials: true
cache-control: max-age=31536000
cf-cache-status: HIT
age: 2348120
expect-ct: max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"
report-to: {"endpoints":[{"url":"https:\/\/a.nel.cloudflare.com\/report\/v3?s=3yPHWrScSsJZoD9oKW6CNGz8cQ8soynfswhiCrGJmEaM63GU80NzHJ9ZxYPatPBXG5gH59Up%2FSzDN%2FIFz8%2BeVBpCoW3C1vBTmkesGMHIloVt%2B8geuoiD22ETykRK6%2FGq"}],"group":"cf-nel","max_age":604800}
nel: {"success_fraction":0,"report_to":"cf-nel","max_age":604800}
server: cloudflare
cf-ray: 6f26e1339a9d681d-SEA
content-encoding: br
alt-svc: h3=":443"; ma=86400, h3-29=":443"; ma=86400


https://fembed-hd.com/asset/default/player/jwplayer.core.controls.html5.js
date: Sun, 27 Mar 2022 08:50:39 GMT
content-type: application/javascript; charset=UTF-8
vary: Accept-Encoding
vary: Accept-Encoding
last-modified: Sat, 30 Mar 2019 16:13:47 GMT
etag: W/"5c9f95bb-43996"
access-control-allow-credentials: true
cache-control: max-age=31536000
cf-cache-status: HIT
age: 2348120
expect-ct: max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"
report-to: {"endpoints":[{"url":"https:\/\/a.nel.cloudflare.com\/report\/v3?s=cNSoqARaRq3DpCbrpcfgv8dhq1AaD8mXfohqdfhKAL1LksUD1zbaSTyP%2FJE7%2FcsOwYGbOAhuf9ZhkVdtVMTp6ouaX8ASanAu63KPr89iAlnNt1Fmh4%2FdV5VdM3MtQhcT"}],"group":"cf-nel","max_age":604800}
nel: {"success_fraction":0,"report_to":"cf-nel","max_age":604800}
server: cloudflare
cf-ray: 6f26e1338a89681d-SEA
content-encoding: br
alt-svc: h3=":443"; ma=86400, h3-29=":443"; ma=86400


https://fembed-hd.com/asset/userdata/376887/player/18015_logo.png?v=1631969623
date: Sun, 27 Mar 2022 08:50:40 GMT
content-type: text/html
content-length: 145
location: https://thumb.fvs.io/asset/userdata/376887/player/18015_logo.png?v=1631969623
cf-cache-status: BYPASS
expect-ct: max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"
report-to: {"endpoints":[{"url":"https:\/\/a.nel.cloudflare.com\/report\/v3?s=8QYFo%2BMEuAcoj%2FrGlX80UUsYoGhkywzxOIj2Mi%2B2duC3bSdR78IvxhuZubYuJeD7tjg4ZgnWNayEQjI4eRyNizZ%2FOmRaXnL3X2vyD2WDurzEHp%2BLMMgMAbuhTAvAnJSM"}],"group":"cf-nel","max_age":604800}
nel: {"success_fraction":0,"report_to":"cf-nel","max_age":604800}
vary: Accept-Encoding
server: cloudflare
cf-ray: 6f26e1375f61681d-SEA
alt-svc: h3=":443"; ma=86400, h3-29=":443"; ma=86400


https://agacelebir.com/4/4370757
server: nginx
date: Sun, 27 Mar 2022 08:50:40 GMT
content-type: text/html; charset=utf8
x-trace-id: 4e17935a83e2b5527000937e2d2c1d89
link: <https://propeller-tracking.com>; rel="preconnect dns-prefetch",<https://my.rtmark.net>; rel="preconnect dns-prefetch"
link: <https://www.gearbest.com>; rel="preconnect dns-prefetch",<https://propeller-tracking.com>; rel="preconnect dns-prefetch",<https://diromalxx.com>; rel="preconnect dns-prefetch"
access-control-allow-origin: *
access-control-allow-credentials: true
access-control-allow-methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS
access-control-allow-headers: Accept, Content-Type, Content-Length, Accept-Encoding
access-control-max-age: 86400
pragma: no-cache
cache-control: no-transform, no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0
expires: Tue, 11 Jan 1994 10:00:00 GMT
timing-allow-origin: *
set-cookie: OAID=6ff7283b32f74cef9a56b08e94875f1c; expires=Mon, 27 Mar 2023 08:50:40 GMT; path=/; secure; SameSite=None
set-cookie: oaidts=1648371040; expires=Mon, 27 Mar 2023 08:50:40 GMT; path=/; secure; SameSite=None
set-cookie: syncedCookie=; expires=Tue, 10 Nov 2009 23:00:00 GMT
pragma: no-cache
cache-control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0
expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT
access-control-allow-origin: *
access-control-allow-methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE
access-control-allow-headers: Accept, Content-Type, Content-Length, Accept-Encoding
content-encoding: gzip


https://adoptexplorationanguish.com/c0/ec/e9/c0ece9150690e04c8083b2de90d71095.js
Server: nginx/1.17.9
Date: Sun, 27 Mar 2022 08:50:40 GMT
Content-Type: application/javascript
Content-Length: 0
Connection: keep-alive
P3P: CP="IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT"
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT
Cache-Control: no-cache
X-Request-ID: b50172e06a63e8dedd2c86ec02d4a96a
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=0; includeSubdomains


https://fvs.io/redirector?token=NEJyUWgrR05CVXR0ZlNZUlFicTYzWDNFYkJ1N0ZZNFgvRWxCbGIzY1Y3U0xmaHdFREc5d3ZvSGRtRWtiUElteHAwUitic1paQUNvU3UvY3MvS0pDTUdHUVhCRGdLL2VVVm9wcXRpZk1EZnNwVHhJazZ4QzQ5UHpqM0JLTlhGcFVBendxb0NrajdNTjE0RFI2cHppbVlmRnZpZ3JCamJJdWR1MD06anpCLzg5TmpPRDFzUFFJZkpQd1Radz09C54s
date: Sun, 27 Mar 2022 08:50:41 GMT
content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
location: https://www279.ff-01.com/token=2iUe05YR1zMldBRstba6pg/1648385436/35.199.0.0/188/f/42/f13e9f316913393ea0de31260543342f-480p.mp4
x-powered-by: PHP/8.0.10
access-control-allow-origin: *
cf-cache-status: DYNAMIC
expect-ct: max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"
server: cloudflare
cf-ray: 6f26e13b0a6908ba-SEA


https://thumb.fvs.io/asset/userdata/376887/player/18015_logo.png?v=1631969623
date: Sun, 27 Mar 2022 08:50:40 GMT
content-type: image/png
content-length: 34616
last-modified: Sat, 18 Sep 2021 12:53:43 GMT
etag: "6145e157-8738"
access-control-allow-origin: *
cache-control: max-age=14400
cf-cache-status: HIT
age: 5033
accept-ranges: bytes
expect-ct: max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"
vary: Accept-Encoding
server: cloudflare
cf-ray: 6f26e13ba83d147a-SEA
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/justforfun/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 174, in _new_conn
    conn = connection.create_connection(
  File "/home/runner/justforfun/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 95, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/home/runner/justforfun/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 85, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/justforfun/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 703, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "/home/runner/justforfun/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 398, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "/home/runner/justforfun/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 239, in request
    super(HTTPConnection, self).request(method, url, body=body, headers=headers)
  File "/nix/store/p21fdyxqb3yqflpim7g8s1mymgpnqiv7-python3-3.8.12/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1256, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/nix/store/p21fdyxqb3yqflpim7g8s1mymgpnqiv7-python3-3.8.12/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1302, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/nix/store/p21fdyxqb3yqflpim7g8s1mymgpnqiv7-python3-3.8.12/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1251, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/nix/store/p21fdyxqb3yqflpim7g8s1mymgpnqiv7-python3-3.8.12/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1011, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/nix/store/p21fdyxqb3yqflpim7g8s1mymgpnqiv7-python3-3.8.12/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 951, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/home/runner/justforfun/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 205, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "/home/runner/justforfun/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 186, in _new_conn
    raise NewConnectionError(
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7fb59c0534c0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 35, in <module>
    driver.close()
  File "/home/runner/justforfun/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 938, in close
    self.execute(Command.CLOSE)
  File "/home/runner/justforfun/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 423, in execute
    response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
  File "/home/runner/justforfun/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py", line 333, in execute
    return self._request(command_info[0], url, body=data)
  File "/home/runner/justforfun/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py", line 355, in _request
    resp = self._conn.request(method, url, body=body, headers=headers)
  File "/home/runner/justforfun/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/request.py", line 74, in request
    return self.request_encode_url(
  File "/home/runner/justforfun/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/request.py", line 96, in request_encode_url
    return self.urlopen(method, url, **extra_kw)
  File "/home/runner/justforfun/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/poolmanager.py", line 376, in urlopen
    response = conn.urlopen(method, u.request_uri, **kw)
  File "/home/runner/justforfun/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 813, in urlopen
    return self.urlopen(
  File "/home/runner/justforfun/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 813, in urlopen
    return self.urlopen(
  File "/home/runner/justforfun/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 813, in urlopen
    return self.urlopen(
  File "/home/runner/justforfun/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 785, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
  File "/home/runner/justforfun/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 592, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=37097): Max retries exceeded with url: /session/587a8792a3385fda1b87cab73e0c8b0a/window (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7fb59c0534c0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))
```

See the second last request in the console output. It is above the errors in the console.

How am I going to capture the location header of that particular request? And how can I get a working url becuase the redirector url or the mp4 url doesn't work.

Comment: I don't see **403 forbidden** in your error tracelogs.

Comment: You won't see it in the trace logs but when you run the code and click on the url you will get 403. Thanks for replying . And help if possible.

Comment: Please answer and help

Answer (score 0):

the token contains the ip from where the request was generated, to see the video it should be with that same ip

Comment: So how can I do that with code plz tell bro.